# Regex: To match two consecutive underscores/hyphens when followed/preceded by any character but not alone

Tags: regex

I am very new to regex. Can someone please guide me if I want to match two consecutive **underscores/hyphens** when followed/preceded by one or more character but not if the underscores/hyphens are alone.

example:

> 1. /--/dsdfsdf/dsfds
> 2. /__/fsfsd/
> 3. /__a/vvfdvds/dsvsdv
> 4. /g--/cdssd/dsdcsd
> 5. /sadsas__/cdscd
> 6. /--sadas/cascs/

In these strings, I don't want to match 1 and 2 but 3, 4, 5 and 6 should be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any underscores in example 5.

But I think this expression would work

```
((-{2}|_{2})[[:alnum:]])|([[:alnum:]](-{2}|_{2}))
```

Comment: It is not working for :
/--/dsdfsdf/dsfds ; 
/__/fsfsd/ ; 
/__a/vvfdvds/dsvsdv ; 
/r--/cdssd/dsdcsdbj ; 
/bjbj__/bbjnbhbh/bhh

Comment: Is that a single string? That is not what you asked for in the original question (in my opinion)

Comment: It is not a single string. Strings are separated by ';' . There are 5 strings

Comment: Sorry I missed a leading ( when copying. Please try again. I have updated the expression

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex:

```
\B(?:--|__)\b|\b(?:--|__)\B
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZKNUy/1)

Explanation:

- \B(?:--|**)\b|\b(?:--|**)\B
- 1st Alternative \B(?:--|__)\b

  - \B assert position where \b does not match
  - Non-capturing group (?:--|__)
  - 1st Alternative --
  - -- matches the characters -- literally (case sensitive)
  - 2nd Alternative __
  - __ matches the characters __ literally (case sensitive)
  - \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
- 2nd Alternative \b(?:--|__)\B

  - \b assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
  - Non-capturing group (?:--|__)
  - 1st Alternative --
  - -- matches the characters -- literally (case sensitive)
  - 2nd Alternative __
  - __ matches the characters __ literally (case sensitive)
  - \B assert position where \b does not match